# vscode java doesn't work with multi-project layout gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

java vscode doesn't work well with multi-project layout gradle project. I can simply reproduce this with the sample project generated by `gradle init`.

The error msg looks like some building task dependency issues: `Cannot use Gradle object after build has finished`

I've described the issue here https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1984

Just want see if anyone have met such issue before and any idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a demo gradle project by [Spring Initializr Java Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr), with `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` generated automatically, so when i run `gradle init`, it would throw `> Task :init SKIPPED` because settings file and build file already existed.

After i delete them manually, `gradle init` could be executed successfully and re-generate `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`:

[image]

I've noticed the comment below your github issue:

> This issue seems similar to another one I'm seeing with eclipse
> buildship, so most likely it's an issue happening in latest gradle
> version

And I'm using **Gradle 7.0.2**, there's no error shown. You may have a try.